# Missing Standard Deviation Values

Tags: missing-data, metadata

Currently trying to conduct a meta-analysis. I have reviewed the references I would like to use and made sure each reference met my criteria for this meta-analysis. However, majority of the references do not include or share any standard deviation value.

For a few references, I was able to use their graphical data and roughly estimate the standard deviation with the errors bars on the graphs. However, most of the other references do not have graphs. Instead, they use tables or just write out their data within paragraphs. I have also tried emailing and reaching out to the different authors of these references and asked if they could share their standard deviation data. Unfortunately though, only a few responded back, some don't know where their data is, and others have not responded back at all.

I'm curious how to calculate the missing standard deviation for those references that do not share that value. Some references mention LSD, coefficient variation, p-value, etc. Is there a mathematical way to calculate the standard deviation from the published data alone? Or is there another way to calculate a common standard deviation for all references lacking that data? Since most articles do not share SD values, should I not include SD in my analysis?

I appreciate any answers to my question.

Answer (score 0):

This article may help you about your concern.

Weir, Christopher J., et al. "Dealing with missing standard deviation and mean values in meta-analysis of continuous outcomes: a systematic review." BMC medical research methodology 18.1 (2018): 1-14.

https://doi.org/10.1186/s12874-018-0483-0